# Can an ECDH key be derived from an ECDSA key?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I have an ECDSA key and I would like to create an ECDH key from it for encryption purposes, is it possible to derive an ECDH key from the ECDSA key in some fashion? Thanks!

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32520/18298

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3260/18298

Comment: The key pairs for both algorithms are technically identical; there is not really an ECDSA or ECDH key pair, just EC key pairs. The posts that kelalaka points  out just show you can use a key pair for both (relatively?) securely.